# Pfsense installation on Desktop Machine

Tags: pfsense, desktop

I am able to install pfsense 2.1 into VirtualBox and Alix device properly.
I want to know if it is possible to install pfsense on my desktop mahine directly. I mean desktop machine does not have OS, so pfsense will control the hardware directly as an OS.

**UPDATE:**
Actually I belive it could be possible. But I am using pfSense-LiveCD-2.1-BETA1-i386-20130330-0246.iso and preparing bootable cd. But it does not start to installa automatically after inserting cd drive.
Instead just grup console is come out.

Am I using wrong pfsense version?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you read [the manual's page on installing](https://doc.pfsense.org/index.php/Installing_pfSense#LiveCD_.2F_Hard_Drive), it explains that the LiveCD can be used as installation media.

> At the same time the LiveCD is the installer which can setup pfSense
>   to your hard disk. It's recommended that you first configure pfSense
>   before you run the installer (option 99 at the shell menu).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, of course it is possible.

Comment: Updated question.

Comment: So, you ask a question, get an answer, and then change your question so that the answer to your first question is no longer valid? Not to mention that this appears to be off topic here.

Comment: @slm if you view the edit history, you will see that the question originally asked simply "can it be installed on a desktop" to which the answer is a simple "yes"

Comment: @MDMarra - thanks didn't think to look there, I knew something was up given your rep but went towards saying something. Thanks I'll look in the edit history next time something like this comes up 8-).

Comment: Understood. By all means, don't be afraid to flag! :) I just wanted to explain my short answer

Comment: decision of authority is always argued. Anyway I have already installed pfsense and configured it as a firewall, vpn server and IDS/IPS system in one machine. That is why I like stackoverflow, even if my question is down voted, which triggers me to search my question over google eagerly.